# MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with `""`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

[image]

When a value is entered in the input of the autocomplete component I get this warning that I can't remove...
This is what my input looks like

```
 <Autocomplete
            id="cboAdresse"
            sx={{ width: 100 + "%", fontFamily: "Poppins Bold" }}
            getOptionLabel={(option) =>
              typeof option === "string" ? option : option.label
            }
            filterOptions={(x) => {
              return x;
            }}
            options={lstadresse}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
              value.label === option.label
            }
            autoComplete
            includeInputInList
            filterSelectedOptions
            value={adresse}
            noOptionsText="Aucune adresse trouvée"
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
              setLstAdresse(
                newValue.name ? [newValue.name, ...lstadresse] : lstadresse
              );
              setAdresse(newValue.name);
              if (newValue.name != "") {
                setVille(newValue.city);
                setCodePostal(newValue.postcode);
              }
            }}
            onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
              setInputRue(newInputValue);
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <div
                ref={params.InputProps.ref}
                className="login-block__input form_input_white"
              >
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="adresse"
                  placeholder="Adresse"
                  {...params.inputProps}
                />
              </div>
            )}
      />
```

We can see that I have integrated the IsOptionEqualToValue parameter without solving the problem. During my research other people have faced this problem and solved it with what I wrote with the IsOptionEqualToValue. If anyone has a solution I'm interested. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

in mui v5 use this

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.value === value.value}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is what I already have in the topic code. I also tested as you wrote it does not work (I have no more suggestions for autocompletions)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use null to represent no value for the Autocomplete component. I have the following code in my wrapper around the Autocomplete component.

```
const { 
    // ... other props
    value: valueProp,
     } = props;

// ...

let value = valueProp;
if (valueProp == null || valueProp = '') {
    valueProp = null
}
return (
    <Autocomplete
        clearOnBlur
        value={valueProp}
    />
);
```

The clear onBlur is needed because of other issues that pop up when using null. See [my comment](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32537#issuecomment-2026276956) on their github for more details

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I've found is to just add an empty string to your options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).